# C# - ContextMenuStrip strange Behaviour

Tags: c#, contextmenu

i have the following code:

```
  ContextMenuStrip cm1 = new ContextMenuStrip();
  ToolStripMenuItem item1 = new ToolStripMenuItem();
  ToolStripMenuItem item2 = new ToolStripMenuItem();
  cm1.Items.Add(item1);
  cm1.Items.Add(item2);
  ContextMenuStrip cm2 = new ContextMenuStrip();
  foreach(ToolStripMenuItem item in cm1.Items)
  {
    cm2.Items.Add(item);
  }
```

Why does the cm2.Items.Add() changes the cm1.Items? They are different (different hashcodes)

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

A menu item can have only one parent at a time. Your foreach loop is simply moving the items from `cm1` to `cm2`.

Comment: i need a default context menue which i can add some other menu items, depending on the context. is there any solution?

Comment: If you're talking about multiple context menu configurations per control, then your best bet is to build each context menu from scratch in your `Click` event handler then present it. Please consider that, although I have not solved your overall problem, I have answered exactly the question you originally asked.